# Assembly language program to simulate a decimal upcounter

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

Here is an assembly language program to simulate a decimal upcounter. but the output gets stuck at 00. Why?

```
.model small


.code
        call cls

        mov ch,30h
        mov cl,30h

  next: mov dh,12
        mov dl,38
        mov bx,00
        mov ah,2
        int 10h

        mov dl,ch
        mov ah,2
        int 21h

        mov dl,cl
        mov ah,2
        int 21h

        inc cl

        call dely

        cmp cl,39h
        jbe next

        mov cl,30h
        inc ch
        cmp ch,39h
        jbe next

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h

   cls  proc near
        mov cx,55
        mov dl,13
    nl: mov ah,2
        int 21h
        loop nl
        ret
        cls endp

  dely proc near
        mov SI,05fffh
     L1:mov DI,05fffh
     L2:dec DI
        jnz L2
        dec SI
        jnz L1
        ret
        dely endp

        end
```

Comment: `int 10h` may ruin your `CX` register.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that your `dely` procedure waits too long so you think it's stuck. Try loading `SI` with something less, values around 10 seems to work fine here.